# over query limit also with setTimeout

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to use google maps geocoder and  getting over query limit.
this is my code

```
var geocoder;
var map;
function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 12,
        center: latlng
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
}
function codeAddress() {
    for (var i = 1; i < 20; i++) {
        var address = document.getElementById('address' + " " + i).value;
        setTimeout(geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: results[0].geometry.location
                });
            } else {
                alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
            }
        }));
    }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize, codeAddress.bind);
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify the delay(2nd argument of `setTimeout`)

You must set it to an incrementing value to avoid the error, e.g. `i*150` , then the calls will be after 150ms,300ms,450ms and so on

```
function codeAddress() {
    for (var i = 1; i < 20; i++) {
        var address = document.getElementById('address' + " " + i).value;
        setTimeout(geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, 
          function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: results[0].geometry.location
                });
            } else {
                alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' +
                       status);
            }
        }),
        i*150//<-delay for the timeout   in ms
        );

    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure I know how to put it in code can u please show me ?

Comment: It look like I was happy to soon, I'm still getting this error ,
 I have tried givint the time delay up to 1500 ms. And down to 50 ,
 I'm still facing it ,
 Any idea why ?

Comment: probably you have reached another limit(daily)

Comment: I don’t think so -, is there a way to check it ?

Comment: Why don't you think so?