# SetTimeout on Directionservice route in google map javascript API

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am using Directionservice of Google Map JavaScript API. Actually I am not able to display more than 10 routes in my map. If I am trying to display more than 10 routes then it is throwing the OVER_QUERY_LIMIT error. 
Even though after setting the setTimeout function not able to display all the routes. I am using only 20 routes to display on the map and not able to display those 20 routes. But if I use the setInterval function then am able to see the all the routes but not able to stop the interval with clearInterval function too so it is going in infinite loop.

```js
function buildRoute(from, to, fromId, toId, index) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    var color = setColor(index);
    var rendererOptions = {
      map: myMap,
      suppressMarkers: true,
      polylineOptions: {
        strokeColor: color
      }
    };

    var directionsRequest = {
      origin: from,
      destination: to,
      travelMode: getTraveMode(),
      unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC
    };

    directionsService.route(directionsRequest, function(response, status) {

      count = count + 1;
      console.log(count + " " + fromId + " " + toId);
      if (status != google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK)
        console.log(status);
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        counter = counter + 1;
        var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(
          rendererOptions);
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        custimiseDriection(response, fromId, toId, color);
        if (counter == totRoutes) {
          // clearInterval();
          displayTimeandDistance();
        }
      }
    })
  }, 1000)
}
```

The SetTimeout function is used at different places in the below code as like below but not able to overcome the OVER_QUERY_LIMIT.

1. setTimeOut(buildRoute(from, to, fromId, toId, index), 1000)
2. Just enclosed the directionservice.route function in setTimeout function
3. Just enclosed the callback function code of directionservice.route is the setTimeout function.

Here is the screen shot of OVER_QUERY_LIMIT errors in chrome console.
[OVER QUERY LIMIT Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrewI.png)

Comment: you must  increase the delay: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22590758/over-query-limit-also-with-settimeout/22591315#22591315

Comment: No it's not working by increasing the delay gradually as like i * 150, I tried with i * 1000 as well.

Comment: curious, works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/n99bge9v/

Comment: Thanks for the information @Dr.Molle. I will try this with my code and will let you know the results.

Answer (score 0):

The client side DirectionService is created to respond to user interaction and this is why your requests are getting throttled - you cannot expect the JS Maps API library to be able to perform more than 10 requests in a burst.

If you need to make an analysis of a number of routes you can consider using the server side directions service since it has usage limits which are [documented](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/usage-limits#standard-usage-limits) and you can enable billing to get higher quotas.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply kaskader. Okay I need to use the serve side Direction services. Let me try out this option.

Comment: Yes. The server side service has usage limits which are documented: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/usage-limits and you can enable billing to get higher quotas.

Comment: @Kaskeder, actually I used the google web service Directionservice API calls but having problem in displaying the route on google map and same is discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35921878/error-in-displaying-directions-webservice-result-on-to-the-google-map). Could you help me by suggesting alternatives to display the routes on top of google maps?