# Google Maps display route from json

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have the next problem to display a route from basic JSON.

1. I do a this call on backend side:
   `curl to https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json`
2. I send back the response json to frontend
3. In frontend I try render the route just for visual, why I don't use the google v3 API to get routeResponse object is because I don't want duplicate the same config as backend use and translate to requestObejct in frontent
4. I try to create the routeResponse json based on backend json from googleapi:

> ```
> data.overviewRouteDirectionSteps.bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
> data.overviewRouteDirectionSteps.bounds.southwest,data.overviewRouteDirectionSteps.bounds.northeast);
>
> data.overviewRouteDirectionSteps.overview_path=google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath(data.overviewRouteDirectionSteps.overview_polyline.points);
>
> data.overviewRouteDirectionSteps.overview_polyline = data.overviewRouteDirectionSteps.overview_polyline.points;
>
> directionsDisplay.setDirections({
>     request: {
>         travelModel: 'DRIVING'
>     },
>     routes: [data.overviewRouteDirectionSteps]
> });
> ```

The problem is I see the start and end markers + legs points but don't see the line:

[image]

What should I do to have a correct display routes ?
Similar with the flow code:

```
directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status === 'OK') {
        console.log(response);
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    } else {
        console.log('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
    }
})
```

Comment: related question: [error in displaying Directions webservice result on to the google map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35921878/error-in-displaying-directions-webservice-result-on-to-the-google-map)

Comment: Hi, in your suggestion the correct response use the javascript google object that are return from `directionsService.route`, for I must create manual that object, and my question how to create this object correctly ?

Comment: What have you tried? What errors do you get doing that?

Comment: I don't get error, I just want to parse the JSON from `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json` and display the route not just show the step points

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Given you made a backend request to Directions webservice, and you're passing the complete response to your frontend, you'll need to process the results for them to become a valid DirectionResult object. This is how I'd do it:

```
if (response.status === 'OK') {


  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(response.routes[0].bounds.southwest, response.routes[0].bounds.northeast);
  response.routes[0].bounds = bounds;

  response.routes[0].overview_path = google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath(response.routes[0].overview_polyline.points);


  response.routes[0].legs = response.routes[0].legs.map(function (leg) {
    leg.start_location = new google.maps.LatLng(leg.start_location.lat, leg.start_location.lng);
    leg.end_location = new google.maps.LatLng(leg.end_location.lat, leg.end_location.lng);
    leg.steps = leg.steps.map(function (step) {
      step.path = google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath(step.polyline.points);
      step.start_location = new google.maps.LatLng(step.start_location.lat, step.start_location.lng);
      step.end_location = new google.maps.LatLng(step.end_location.lat, step.end_location.lng);
      return step;
    });
    return leg;
  });

  directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
}
```

Basically, when you use the [google.maps.DirectionsService](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/directions) class, the library takes care, on your behalf, to transform to and from two actors:

1. The routing service (backend [Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/overview#DirectionsResponses)) in charge of providing a route solution for the question "how do I get from A to B"? It  makes no assumptions about the way you will use its result.
2. The drawing service (frontend [google.maps.DirectionsRenderer class](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/directions#DirectionsRenderer))  in charge of showing the user the visual representation of a generic (but detailed) route. It makes no assumptions on where did you get the routing solution from as long as you feed it the right structure (it is expecting an instance of [google.maps.DirectionsResult](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/directions#DirectionsResult)).

When you chose to use curl or any other server side library to request for directions, you filled the gap to translate the frontend  [google.maps.DirectionsRequest](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/directions#DirectionsRequest) object into a properly URL encoded [Directions API Request](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/overview#request-parameters). Now you need to translate the [Directions API Response](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/overview#DirectionsResponses) back into an instance of [google.maps.DirectionsResult](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/directions#DirectionsResult).

Even if the JSON result is mostly an object, the renderer does not and should not assume that a plain object should be used to instance paths, routes, positions or legs.

Comment: Thank you, works perfect, just 1 more question, why the route have dots and is not a simple line? I already puut the travelModel to be DRIVING  `request: {
                                            travelModel: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
                                        }` )

Comment: In my example or in yours? Perhaps you need to tinker with your renderer options

Comment: this is my render options: `{ suppressInfoWindows: true, suppressMarkers: true, suppressBicyclingLayer: true, polylineOptions: { fillColor: '#FF0000', strokeOpacity: 1.0, strokeWeight: 10 }, travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING }` and not show a line, more then that the color not apply, What I do wrong ?

Comment: well, polylines don't have fillColor, they have strokeColor. But it should default to black

Comment: ok, but how I do the continue line insteand of dot line ? like Polyline object

Comment: You're saying that using my example it still displays only the vertices of the polyline?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158620/discussion-between-laurentiu-and-amenadiel).

Comment: There is a problem that centre is thrown to the middle of the pacific. How come?

Comment: make sure you aren't swapping lat/lng

Comment: Well that was my issue, I fixed that. BTW where did you get this information from?

Comment: directions.js:43 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'travelMode')

Comment: append request with your travel mode to the response to fix your error @RahmadAlHabib:

`response.request = {  travelModel: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING                                         }`